# Android connecting on hotspot server address returns ConnectException

Tags: android, networking, serversocket, hotspot

So I am developing a chat app and whenever I connect to the server IP address (192.168.43.1) via a socket it returns:

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.43.1 (port 8989): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
```

The address is correct since I got it from DhcpInfo and the port too is correct because if I supplied *localhost* on my device, it can connect.
Can someone explain here what I am missing.

Thanks for your time.

EDIT:

here is the code for generating the server:

```
ServerSocket server_socket = new ServerSocket(8989);
Socket client_connection = server_socket.accept();
```

and for the client:

```
Socket client_socket = new Socket("192.168.43.1", 8989);
```

Comment: did you put http:// before url?

Comment: No, this is in the case of creating a Java Socket that will connect to the ServerSocket